# CD./DVD drive (D) lost after windows 10 installation

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10-upgrade

Hello I was trying to install a new PC game and notice that my computer is unable to read it.  when i tried to manually open the D drive to run the CD it was gone.  How do i recover this drive.

When i go on my computer all i see is drive C, USB drive  F and USB drive G.

Please can someone help me.  I can run my games.

Comment: If you restart does it return?  Go into your firmware is the drive listed there?

Comment: This is a common problem when upgrading to W10, I don't get all the down votes.

Comment: @Moab The votes indicate that there is no research effort shown on this question (hover over the arrows) - just "Here's a problem, how do I fix it". If it's a common problem, then the asker should be able to easily find the answer elsewhere on site, or Google...

Comment: Votes are opinions, nothing more. Sometimes their research effort brings them here.

Answer (score 2):

Go into **Device Manager** and under **View** select **Show Hidden Devices**. Uninstall these IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers:

ATA Channel 0,
ATA Channel 1,
Intel (R).... Serial ATA Storage Controller)

Reboot and Windows 10 should now detect that there is a DVD. Follow driver installation and you should be all set.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/windows-10-dvd-drive-missing/f246ef3d-ff9a-4cd2-9746-7de01184c258?auth=1)